# Node.js paypal rest api error401

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal

I am trying to create an invoice with Paypal rest API. I got an error 
Error: Response Status : 401
Which is not saying more than that. I have double-checked my secret and id are correct and the mode is set to sandbox. I can't find anything wrong since I just copy-pasted in the example code to get started

Everything, making new client on PayPal developer portal. Just nothing makes sense anymore..

```
const config = require("../configs/bot_settings.json")
// PayPal //
const paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');

paypal.configure({
    mode: config.paypal_mode, // Sandbox or live
    client_id: config.paypal_id,
    client_secret: config.paypal_secret
});
// PayPal //
var create_invoice_json = {
    "merchant_info": {
        "email": "PPX.DevNet-facilitator@gmail.com",
        "first_name": "Dennis",
        "last_name": "Doctor",
        "business_name": "Medical Professionals, LLC",
        "phone": {
            "country_code": "001",
            "national_number": "5032141716"
        },
        "address": {
            "line1": "1234 Main St.",
            "city": "Portland",
            "state": "OR",
            "postal_code": "97217",
            "country_code": "US"
        }
    },
    "billing_info": [{
        "email": "example@example.com"
    }],
    "items": [{
        "name": "Sutures",
        "quantity": 100.0,
        "unit_price": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "value": 5
        }
    }],
    "note": "Medical Invoice 16 Jul, 2013 PST",
    "payment_term": {
        "term_type": "NET_45"
    },
    "shipping_info": {
        "first_name": "Sally",
        "last_name": "Patient",
        "business_name": "Not applicable",
        "phone": {
            "country_code": "001",
            "national_number": "5039871234"
        },
        "address": {
            "line1": "1234 Broad St.",
            "city": "Portland",
            "state": "OR",
            "postal_code": "97216",
            "country_code": "US"
        }
    },
    "tax_inclusive": false,
    "total_amount": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "500.00"
    }
};

paypal.invoice.create(create_invoice_json, function (error, invoice) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log("Create Invoice Response");
        message.channel.send(invoice.total_amount)
        console.log(invoice.total_amount);
    }
});
```

Comment: console.log(config.paypal_id) console.log(config.paypal_secret) and see if those values are present.

Comment: Also, try to see if the sandbox version works if it does then your issue is going to be with your credentials.

Comment: @Rami Tried everything its loggin everything correctly,,,